# Select node by node text

Tags: .net

I have to following XML file:

```
<root xmlns="http://someurl/element" xmlns:text="http://someurl/text">
   <elements>
     <element>
       <Id>text:SOME_ID</Id>
        <!-- some other elements -->
     </element>
      <element>
       <!-- some other elements -->
        <reference>
          <link ref="text:SOME_ID" />
        </reference>
     </element>
   </elements>
 </root>
```

I want to select all child elements of the elment node which have the element Id=text:SOME_ID, how can i get it using xmldocument method

Comment: Do you *have* to use XmlDocument instead of LINQ to XML?

Comment: Use XPath expressions. Check http://www.w3schools.com/xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it is not entirely clear to me what you want to select but I assume you want to select `<element>` having child `<Id>` with content `text:SOME_ID`.

If you insist on using `XmlDocument` you can use it like this:

```
IEnumerable<XPathNavigator> GetElements(String xml, String id) {
  var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
  xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);
  var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);
  namespaceManager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://someurl/element");
  var navigator = xmlDocument.CreateNavigator();
  var xPath = "//ns:element/ns:Id[. = '" + id + "']/..";
  return navigator.Select(xPath, namespaceManager).Cast<XPathNavigator>();
}
```

However, I recommend using LINQ to XML:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> GetElements(String xml, String id) {
  XNamespace ns = "http://someurl/element";
  var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);
  return xDocument
    .Descendants(ns + "element")
    .Where(element => (String) element.Element(ns + "Id") == id);
}
```